# how to put a generic Qt Quick's control inside a Menu

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

How may I put a generic Qt Quick's control inside a Menu?
Something like:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    menu: Menu {
        MenuItem { }
        Slider { }
        Button { }
    }
}
```

with "standard" Qt you can do that with a QWidgetAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the stock menu is pretty much limited to text.

However, you can toy around with the `MenuStyle` element, and create a style that uses a custom item for the menu delegate which you specify via extra property.

Implementing your own menu component is also a viable solution, especially because:

> Note: Styling menus may not be supported on platforms using native
>   menus through their QPA plugin.

I always take the latter approach, because I use UI that is consistent across different platforms and requires functionality which the stock menu elements don't provide.